# Spacy PhraseMatcher - match not one of the keywords but ALL keywords within string

Tags: python, spacy

I am trying to solve the task of classifying texts into buckets based on the keywords. It is fairly easy to do when I need to match the text with one or several keywords (so one of keywords shall be in text), however I have trouble understanding how to do the matching when I need to ensure that several of keywords exist within the string.

Below is a small sample. Let's say that my `dfArticles` is a pandas dataframe which has a column `Text` with the text articles I am trying to match:

```
dfArticles['Text']
Out[2]: 
0       (Reuters) - Major Middle Eastern markets ended...
1       MIDEAST STOCKS-Oil price fall hurts major Gulf...
2       DUBAI, 21st September, 2020 (WAM) -- The Minis...
3       DUBAI, (UrduPoint / Pakistan Point News / WAM ...
4       Brent crude was down 99 cents or 2.1% at $42.2.
```

Let's also say that my dataframe `dfTopics` holds a list of keywords I am trying to match against and buckets associated with keywords:

```
dfTopics
Out[3]: 
            Topic              Keywords
0     Regulations                   law
1     Regulations            regulatory
2     Regulations            regulation
3     Regulations           legislation
4     Regulations                 rules
5          Talent            capability
6          Talent             workforce
```

When I just need to check if the text is matching one of this keywords it is simple:

```
def prep_match_patterns(dfTopics):
    
    matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab, attr="LOWER")
    
    for topic in dfTopics['Topic'].unique():
        keywords = dfTopics.loc[dfTopics['Topic'] == topic, 'Keywords'].to_list()
        patterns_topic = [nlp.make_doc(text) for text in keywords]
        matcher.add(topic, None, *patterns_topic)
    return matcher
```

Then I can easily check with one shot which buckets the text falls into:

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")
nlp.disable_pipes(["parser"])
# extract the sentences from the documents
nlp.add_pipe(nlp.create_pipe('sentencizer'))

matcher = prep_match_patterns(dfTopics)


dfResults = pd.DataFrame([],columns=['ArticleID', 'Topic'])


articles = []
topics = []


for index, row in tqdm(dfArticles.iterrows(), total=len(dfArticles)):
    doc = nlp(row['Text'])
    matches = matcher(doc)
    if len(matches)<1:
        continue
    else:
        for match_id, start, end in matches:
            string_id = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id]  # Get string representation
            articles.append(row['ID'])
            topics.append(string_id)
    
dfResults['ArticleID'] = articles
dfResults['Topic'] = topics


dfResults.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
```

**But now the trick is - sometimes to classify the text into bucket I need to ensure it matches several keywords at the same time**

Let's say I have a new topic called *"Healthcare system context"* and for text to fall into this bucket I need the text to have all 3 substrings in it: *"fragmentation" and "approval process" and "drug"*. Order doesn't matter but all three keywords need to be there. Is there any way to do it with PhraseMatcher?

Comment: What if you have in your text not the exact keyword, but a derivative of it? What if you have say 4 matches out of 5? What if partial list matches 2 categories at the same time? Any specific reason to do it with spacy?

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov her Sergey. Idea is that for every bucket I have several matching patterns and if text matches any of patterns I consider it a match. If text matches several categories - so be it, I am capturing both matches. Exact or derivatives don’t matter, in reality I run everything after doing stemming, here is just a simplified example. I am not married to using spacy at all, I am just trusting my existing code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're overcomplicating. You can achieve what you want with simple python.

Suppose we have:

```
df_topics
    Topic   Keywords
0   Regulations law
1   Regulations regulatory
2   Regulations regulation
3   Regulations legislation
4   Regulations rules
5   Talent  capability
6   Talent  workforce
```

Then you can organize your topic keywords into a dictionary:

```
topics = df_topics.groupby("Topic")["Keywords"].agg(lambda x: x.to_list()).to_dict()
topics
{'Regulations': ['law', 'regulatory', 'regulation', 'legislation', 'rules'],
 'Talent': ['capability', 'workforce']}
```

Finally, define a func to match keywords:

```
def textToTopic(text, topics):
    t = []
    for k,v in topics.items():
        if all([topic in text.split() for topic in v]):
            t.append(k)
    return t
```

Demo:

```
textToTopic("law regulatory regulation rules legislation workforce", topics)
['Regulations']
```

---

```
textToTopic("law regulatory regulation rules legislation workforce capability", topics)
['Regulations', 'Talent']
```

You can apply this func to a text in `df`

Comment: Hey Sergey. Sorry for delay. Yes it does, looks neat! I am a bit surpriced though that spacy seems to be faster than this pure python approach (PhraseMatcher is almost 2X faster in my case). But it gets me around the problem with finding "all keywords in text" problem, so thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! If 2X `PhraseMatcher` is preferrable, you may follow the same logic with `all()`, where you feed your phrase matcher to `all`. But the logic is still the same: no way to load this logic directly, use a workaround.